# remove english characters and keep only foreign unicode characters

Tags: android, kotlin

I have this regex grep command that is working as expected.
It separates all english characters and punctuation from foreign characters.

```
head -300  tb.txt | grep  -h '[A-Za-z0-9[:punct:]]'
```

But I am not sure how to remove those characters and keep only foreign characters in a text file.

For e.g. if I have this text:

```
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "WebPage",
  "name": "गृहनिर्माण सोसायटीच्या माजी सचिवांना तीन लाखांचा दंड; उच्च न्यायालयाचा निर्णय, वाचा सविस्तर",
  "description": "<p> नगर सहकारी गृहनिर्माण संस्थेचे माजी सचिव चिंतामण पांडे यांना सहकारी संस्थेच्या डी/ई-प्रभागाच्या उपनिबंधकाने ३ मार्च २०२२ रोजी याचिकाकर्त्याला पाच वर्षांसाठी गृहनिर्माण संस्थेची निवडणूक लढवण्यास पात्र ठरवले. गृहनिर्माण संस्थेचे सचिव म्हणून वार्षिक सर्वसाधारण सभा आयोजित न केल्याबद्दल याचिकाकर्त्याला दोषी ठरवून ठरवून उपरोक्त कारवाई केली होती.</p>
",
  "image":"https://s.navarashtra.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/cropped-navarashtra-logo.png",
```

The expected is this:

```
गृहनिर्माण सोसायटीच्या माजी सचिवांना तीन लाखांचा दंड; उच्च न्यायालयाचा निर्णय, वाचा सविस्तर

नगर सहकारी गृहनिर्माण संस्थेचे माजी सचिव चिंतामण पांडे यांना सहकारी संस्थेच्या डी/ई-प्रभागाच्या उपनिबंधकाने ३ मार्च २०२२ रोजी याचिकाकर्त्याला पाच वर्षांसाठी गृहनिर्माण संस्थेची निवडणूक लढवण्यास पात्र ठरवले. गृहनिर्माण संस्थेचे सचिव म्हणून वार्षिक सर्वसाधारण सभा आयोजित न केल्याबद्दल याचिकाकर्त्याला दोषी ठरवून ठरवून उपरोक्त कारवाई केली होती.
```

---

Update:

This highlight the expected text. But how do I return only the highlighted/ selected text?

```
grep "$(printf '[\u0900-\u097F]')" tb.txt
```

---

Update 2:

I am looking for a way to re-write the above statement in Kotlin.

Comment: There is no such thing as "_English characters_" There are Indian-Arabic digits, characters from the Roman alphabet, etc. Do you mean you want to remove the 128 ASCII characters and keep all others? Moreover, characters and their encoding are two different things so one important information is missing in your question: what is the encoding of your source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to use this one liner in Kotlin? I do not want to preserve dots (. periods)

You'd get the file text into a buffered reader, read lines into a list, and slice that to the no. of desired lines, and apply the regex to filter out the ASCII chars.

There are two working forms of that regex:

```
Regex("[\\p{ASCII}*&&[^. ]]")
Regex("[\\x00-\\x7F&&[^. ]]")
```

Note, the period `.` and space   are both preserved with `[^. ]`

And here's the extension function on the `File` that takes in the no. of lines you'd like to apply that from the file.

```
fun File.getForeignUnicode(nlines: Int): String {
    val regex = Regex("[\\p{ASCII}*&&[^. ]]")
    val text = bufferedReader().readLines().let { lines ->
        lines.slice(0..min(lines.count() - 1, nlines - 1)).joinToString(separator = "\n")
    }
    return regex.replace(text, "")
}
```

Usage:

```
// Assuming the file resides in `filesDir` named as "tb.txt"
val file =  File(filesDir, "tb.txt")
val text = file.getForeignUnicode(300)
print(text)
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipe it through `sed` to remove all ascii except the dot:

```
| sed 's,[!--/-~],,g'
```

In situ:

```
head -300  tb.txt | grep  -h '[A-Za-z0-9[:punct:]]' | sed 's,[!--/-~],,g'
```

This character class is two ranges; one from `!` (the first printable ascii character) to `-` (the character before the dot) and a second range from `/` (the character after the dot) to `~` (the last ascii char).

Comment: Is it possible to keep the full stops? This has removed the periods "." as well.

Comment: `[!--/-~]` would keep the `ASCII` periods (`.`) for u. `[-!-+/-~]` would keep `ASCII` comma  (`,`) and period  (`.`) . `[-!-&(-+/-~]` would add `ASCII` apostrophe  (`'`)  to that list. To add the tilder  (`~`), change the tilde inside any of those `regex` I listed to `}` instead. No need to add extra backslash to any of that stuff.

Comment: @shantanuo I have edited my answer to preserve dots.

Comment: unbelievably easy. I was trying to do this in python and it was getting unnecessarily complicated. Appreciated.